# how can i convert my matlab conde into mathematica or atleast convert the bisection program?

Tags: functions, programming, core-language

(*Convert matlab code into mathematica code*)

(*I'm fairly new to mathematica*)

(*bisect function matlab code:*)

```
 function [root,fx,ea,iter]=bisect(func,xl,xu,es,maxit,varargin)
```

(*% bisect: root location zeroes*)

(*% [root,fx,ea,iter]=bisect(func,xl,xu,es,maxit,p1,p2,...):*)

(*% uses bisection method to find the root of func*)

(*% input:*)

(*func = name of function*)

(*% xl, xu = lower and upper guesses*)

(*% es = desired relative error (default = 0.0001%)*)

(*% maxit = maximum allowable iterations (default = 50)*)

(*% p1,p2,... = additional parameters used by func*)

(*% output:*)

(*% root = real root*)

(*% fx = function value at root*)

(*% ea = approximate relative error (%)*)

(*% iter = number of iterations*)

```
 if nargin<3,error('at least 3 input arguments required'),end

 test = func(xl,varargin{:})*func(xu,varargin{:});

 if test>0,error('no sign change'),end

 if nargin<4|isempty(es), es=0.0001;end

 if nargin<5|isempty(maxit), maxit=50;end

 iter = 0; xr = xl; ea = 100;

while (1)

xrold = xr;

 xr = (xl + xu)/2;

 iter = iter + 1;

 if xr ~= 0,ea = abs((xr - xrold)/xr) * 100;end

 test = func(xl,varargin{:})*func(xr,varargin{:});

 if test < 0

 xu = xr;

elseif test > 0

 xl = xr;

 else

 ea = 0;

 end

 if ea <= es | iter >= maxit,break,end

 end

 root = xr; fx = func(xr, varargin{:});
```

(*Problem code*)

```
 clc

 clear all

 close all

 r1 = 0.5;

 r2 = 1;

 h = 1;

 pf= 200;

 pw = 1000;

 fh1 = @(h1)pf*pi*h/(3)*(r1^2 + r2^2 + r1*r2)-...

 pw *pi*(h - h1)/(3).*((r1 + (r2 - r1)/h*h1).^2 + r2^2 + (r1 + (r2 - 
 r1)/h*h1)*r2);

  h1 = (0:h/20:h);

  fhh =fh1(h1);

   plot (h1, fhh),grid

  [height f ea iter]= bisect(fh1, 0, 1);
```

(*here's the picture of the exact problem and equations used to tackle the matlab problem.*)

(*I'm struggling with root function and bisection portion in mathematica*)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8elg.jpg

(*mathematica code i attempted *)

```
func[root, fx, ea, iter] = Bisection[a0_, b0_, m_] :=
 Module[{}, a = N[a0]; b = N[b0]; c = (a + b)/2; k = 0; output = {{k, 
 a, c, b, f[c]}}; While[k < m, If[Sign[f[b]] == Sign[f[c]],
 b = c, a = c;]; c = a + b/2; i = i + 1;
 output = Append[output, {i, a, c, b, f[c]}];];
 Print[NumberForm[TableForm[output,
 TableHeadings \[RightArrow] {None, {"k", "ak", "ck", "bk",
 "f[ck]"}}], 16]];
 Print[" c = ", NumberForm[c, 16]];
 Print[" \[Laplacian]c = \[PlusMinus]", b \[Minus] a/2 ];
 Print["f[c] = ", NumberForm[f[c], 16] ];]

 r1 = 0.5;
 r2 = 1;
 h = 1;
 pf = 200;
 pw = 1000;
 fh1 = function[(h1)] pf*\[Pi]*h/(3)*(r1^2 + r2^2 + r1*r2) -
 pw *\[Pi]*(h - h1)/(3)*((r1 + (r2 - r1)/h*h1)^2 =
 r2^2 + (r1 + (r2 - r1)/h*h1)*r2)
 Plot[OutageProb, {h1, 0, h/20, h}, PlotRange -> {h1, fhh}, ,
 grid {h1, fhh}, Frame -> True]
 fhh = fh1 (h1)
 [height f ea iter] = bisection (fh1, 0, 1)
```

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=bisection brings up at least two implementations of a bisection algorithm. Perhaps you could start from those.

Answer (score 2):

In case it is helpful, I provide a corrected version of your code

```
Bisection[a0_, b0_, m_, f_] := Module[{a, b, c, k, output, i},
  a = N[a0];
  b = N[b0];
  c = (a + b)/2;
  k = 0; 
  output = {{k, a, c, b, f[c]}}; 
  While[k < m, If[Sign[f[b]] == Sign[f[c]], b = c, a = c]; 
   c = (a + b)/2;
   k = k + 1;
   output = Append[output, {k, a, c, b, f[c]}];];
  Print[NumberForm[
    TableForm[output, 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"k", "ak", "ck", "bk", "f[ck]"}}], 
    16]];
  Print[" c = ", NumberForm[c, 16]];
  Print[" δc = ±", (b - a)/2];
  Print["f[c] = ", NumberForm[f[c], 16]];
  output]
```